# visualsvn 2.7.3 with trac 1.0.1

Tags: python, trac, visualsvn-server

VisualSVN website provided a method to install trac 0.12 on top of VisualSVN 2.6.4 (apache web server) with Subversion authentication. this is described at: http://www.visualsvn.com/server/trac/ This works well but recently I had to update to VisualSVN 2.7.3 that includes and update to SVN 1.8.5 and had to also update to Trac 1.0.1. i was able to replace the trac files in the folder and the pages for trac are serving but i get the following error on the wiki:

*"Warning: Can't synchronize with repository "(default)" (Unsupported version control system "svn": DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.). Look in the Trac log for more information."*

The Trac Log file contains the following error:

```
2013-12-23 00:24:13,892 Trac[svn_fs] INFO: Failed to load Subversion bindings
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\tracopt\versioncontrol\svn\svn_fs.py", line 273, in __init__
    _import_svn()
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\tracopt\versioncontrol\svn\svn_fs.py", line 72, in _import_svn
    from svn import fs, repos, core, delta
  File "C:\VisualSVN Server\trac\python\lib\site-packages\svn\fs.py", line 26, in 
    from libsvn.fs import *
  File "C:\VisualSVN Server\trac\python\lib\site-packages\libsvn\fs.py", line 86, in 
    import core
  File "C:\VisualSVN Server\trac\python\lib\site-packages\libsvn\core.py", line 25, in 
    _core = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\VisualSVN Server\trac\python\lib\site-packages\libsvn\core.py", line 21, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_core', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I doubt i am the first to have this issue but I could not find any fixes for this issue. I also emailed VisualSVN about the unsupported plug-in but received no help (understandably so). If anyone has dealt with this issue, knows of a walk-thru for these versons please post.

As a last hope, any one knowing of an alternative way to setup Trac to work with VisulSVN (apache web server) for the mentioned versions, your help is appreciated as well.

Comment: What version of Subversion did the old version of VisualSVN use?  If it something other than v1.8.5, then your Python installation might be using an incompatible set of Subversion libraries (from the old installation).  Open a Python interactive shell and see what happens if you execute the command `from svn import fs, repos, core, delta`.  If you get errors, then you most likely have a SVN/Python library problem.

Comment: I'm unsure of the previous SVN version was off hand, however i know it was not 1.8.5. In the mean time i attempted to update the python bindings per the Trac page [link]http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracSubversion#forPython2.7

Comment: Using the bindings from [link]http://alagazam.net
I ran the python command you suggested and got no errors but i also got no info (stdout/stderr) from it. I believe the bindings are likely the issue but still unable to get it to work.

Comment: No output means that the command completed successfully.  The output in the Trac log shows that Trac threw an error when it tried to run that same `import` command that worked for you.  Follow the Windows troubleshooting steps from http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracSubversion#checklist-windows.  That guide appears to describe your exact error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coincidentally I was having the same issue on the same day you posted your question.  After some searching I found that there is a ticket on the Trac website where others are having a similar issue:

http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/6739

The fix outlined there was virtually the same for me.  I've described my setup + version of the fix below:

---

Running Apache 2.4, with Python 2.7 and Trac 1.0.1 (all 32 bit) on a Win 7 64-bit VM.

For the subversion installation, I used the 1.8.5 Windows installer from Alagazam.net and also the Python 2.7 bindings (win32) for Apache 2.4.

Installed everything as per install guides.  Once everything was installed, I copied the `libapr-1.dll` file from the Subversion bin directory to the Apache bin directory, replacing the existing version of the file there.  Fired up Apache web server to test and all was fine and dandy.  Hope this fixes your issue too...

Comment: Thanks, at the point i had gotten to, all i had to do was copy `libapr-1.dll` from `VisualSVN Server\trac\python\Lib\site-packages\libsvn` to `VisualSVN Server\bin`.